# how do i toggle between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs. I want div id 1 to be visible when the page is loaded and when i click on anywhere in main div id 2 should be visible.when user click again on main 2 should be hidden and 1 visible.`

```
<div id="main" style="border:1 px dashed red;" >
  <div id="1" style="width:300px;height:50px; ">div One visible</div>
  <div id="2" style="width:300px;height:50px; ">div two visible</div>
</div>
```

How do i get it done using Jquery? i am not sure how to get the toggling effect

Thanks

Comment: check the [jquery toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy peasy.

```
$(function ()
{
    var $main = $('#main'),
        $1 = $('#1'),
        $2 = $('#2');
    
    $2.hide(); // hide div#2 when the page is loaded
    
    $main.click(function ()
    {
        $1.toggle();
        $2.toggle();
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/8vbGE/)

---

#### Edit

OP Comment: *"Is there anyway i can keep track of which div is visible?"*

There certainly is; it depends on how you want to use it. You can manually maintain a flag:

```
$(function ()
{
    var $main = $('#main'),
        $1 = $('#1'),
        $2 = $('#2'),
        $visible;
    
    $2.hide(); // hide div#2 when the page is loaded
    $visible = $1;
    
    $main.click(function ()
    {
        $1.toggle();
        $2.toggle();
        $visible = ($visible === $1 ? $2 : $1);
    });
});
```

Or you can just write a function that figures it out for you:

```
$(function ()
{
    var $main = $('#main'),
        $1 = $('#1'),
        $2 = $('#2');
    
    $2.hide(); // hide div#2 when the page is loaded
    
    $main.click(function ()
    {
        $1.toggle();
        $2.toggle();
    });
    
    
    function whichIsVisible()
    {
        if (!$1.is(':hidden')) return $1;
        if (!$2.is(':hidden')) return $2;
    }
});
```

As [jAndy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305000/jandy) points out, this function can be written in a more concise/terse form:

```
function whichIsVisible()
{
    return $1.add($2).filter(':visible');
}
```

However, it **is semantically different** from the first version. The first version returns one of:

- `$1`
- `$2`
- `undefined`

while jAndy's version returns one of:

- `$1`
- `$2`
- `$1.add($2)`, a two-element jQuery object
- `$()`, an empty jQuery object

So they're **not strictly equivalent**.

Comment: @Matt, is there anyway i can keep track of which div is visible.

Comment: In general it's very good to cache DOM references, but for a one-time access it's useless anyway.

Comment: MattBall: `return $1.add($2).filter(':visible');`

Comment: @jAndy: that's definitely more concise. I'll add that in.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like

HTML

```
<div id="main" style="border:1 px dashed red;" >
   <div id="1" style="width:300px;height:50px; ">div One visible</div>
   <div id="2" style="width:300px;height:50px;display:none; ">div two visible</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#main').click(function() {
       $('#1, #2').toggle();
    });
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/74/

Comment: @MattBall: So +.5 for speed, and +.5 for cleanly-ness. Unfortunately my scale uses floor(), thus I can't award you any points... [jk ;p]

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    // start out hiding the second
    $('#2').hide();

    // when they click the main div
    $('#main').click(function(){
        // make one hide and the other show.
        $('#1,#2').toggle();
    });
});
```

Should do the trick. Working example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/3XznV/1/ <strike>(Excuse the red background, wanted to see where to click. ;-)</strike>

EDIT: Fixed your style sheet (border) so the "1"&"px" have no space. ;-)

Comment: +1 for degradation, if js is not enabled, hidden div will not be inaccessable

Answer (score 0):

Working example posted at http://jsfiddle.net/y8uwt/

HTML:

```
<div id="main" style="border:1 px dashed red;" >
  <div id="1" style="width:300px;height:50px; ">div One visible</div>
  <div id="2" style="display:none;width:300px;height:50px; ">div two visible</div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="button">click</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(event) {
        $("#1").toggle();
        $("#2").toggle();
    })
});
```