# What does [object Object] mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to `alert` a returned value from a function and I get this in the alert:

```
[object Object]
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ()
{
    var $main = $('#main'),
    $1 = $('#1'),
    $2 = $('#2');

    $2.hide(); // hide div#2 when the page is loaded

    $main.click(function ()
    {
        $1.toggle();
        $2.toggle();
    });

    $('#senddvd').click(function ()
    {
       alert('hello');
       var a=whichIsVisible();
       alert(whichIsVisible());
    });

    function whichIsVisible()
    {
        if (!$1.is(':hidden')) return $1;
        if (!$2.is(':hidden')) return $2;
    }

});

</script>
```

`whichIsVisible` is the function which I am trying to check on.

Comment: It means the datatype of what you're returning is an Object.

Comment: Out of interest: what are you expecting it to return?

Comment: You should use a JavaScript console to introspect the objects you're interested in (e.g. Firebug).

Comment: related: [Javascript - \[object Object\] means?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8892465/1048572)

Comment: Answer 2 is more clear answer, can you take a look at it, and choose it as accepted answer if you feel the same.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The default conversion from an object to string is `"[object Object]"`.

As you are dealing with jQuery objects, you might want to do

```
alert(whichIsVisible()[0].id);
```

to print the element's ID.

As mentioned in the comments, you should use the tools included in browsers like Firefox or Chrome to introspect objects by doing `console.log(whichIsVisible())` instead of `alert`.

*Sidenote*: IDs should not start with digits.

Comment: [
 In HTML5, IDs can start with digits.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: More generally I'd be concerned that objects may not HAVE an id attribute; for example, if you got an object list just using a css selector like $('.someStyleClass'). To be clear on the identity of whatever object you're dealing with, it might be useful or at least interesting to assign your objects metadata using the jquery .data() function, http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 232):

As others have noted, this is the default serialisation of an object. But why is it `[object Object]` and not just `[object]`?

That is because there are different types of objects in Javascript!

- *Function objects*:
  `stringify(function (){})` -> `[object Function]`
- *Array objects*:
  `stringify([])` -> `[object Array]`
- *RegExp objects*
  `stringify(/x/)` -> `[object RegExp]`
- *Date objects*
  `stringify(new Date)` -> `[object Date]`
- … [several more](http://es5.github.io/spec.html#x15-toc) …
- and **Object objects**!
  `stringify({})` -> `[object Object]`

That's because the constructor function is called `Object` (with a capital "O"), and the term "object" (with small "o") refers to the structural nature of the thingy.

Usually, when you're talking about "objects" in Javascript, you actually *mean* "**Object objects**", and not the other types.

<sub>where `stringify` should look like this:</sub>

```
function stringify (x) {
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(x));
}
```

Comment: If toString() is not overridden in a custom object: per [documentation](https://es5.github.io/x15.2.html#x15.2.4.2) 15.2.4.2 Object.prototype.toString ( ) # Ⓣ Ⓔ Ⓡ
When the toString method is called, the following steps are taken:

If the this value is undefined, return "[object Undefined]".
If the this value is null, return "[object Null]".
Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.
Let class be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of O.
Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings "[object ", class, and "]".

Comment: plus one for terminology of `thingy`

Comment: Good explanation! BTW, JSON.stringify is not the one used here.

Comment: Can you make it more explicit at the top what your stringify function, that it is not `JSON.stringify`, someone can take wrong impression.

Comment: Why does `Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined)` gives `[object Undefined]`?

Answer (score 32):

You can see value inside  [object Object] like this

```
Alert.alert(  JSON.stringify(userDate)  );
```

Try like this

```
    realm.write(() => {
       const userFormData = realm.create('User',{
       user_email: value.username,
       user_password: value.password,
      });
     });

      const userDate = realm.objects('User').filtered('user_email == $0', value.username.toString(), );
      Alert.alert(  JSON.stringify(userDate)  );
```

reference

https://off.tokyo/blog/react-native-object-object/

Comment: How would you access for example, userDate.timezone, or say user.name etc.? In my program, if I do JSON.stringify(object), obviously I can see everything. When I try console.log(object), I get [Object object]... but when I try console.log(object.name), I get undefined. (JSON.stringify(object.name) doesn't work; I get undefined as well :( )

Answer (score 29):

`[object Object]` is the default toString representation of an object in javascript.

If you want to know the properties of your object, just foreach over it like this:

```
for(var property in obj) {
    alert(property + "=" + obj[property]);
}
```

In your particular case, you are getting a jQuery object. Try doing this instead:

```
$('#senddvd').click(function ()
{
   alert('hello');
   var a=whichIsVisible();
   alert(whichIsVisible().attr("id"));
});
```

This should alert the id of the visible element.

Comment: > [object Object] is the default toString representation of an object in javascript. -- this still doesn't explain where it comes from.

Answer (score 23):

**Basics**

You may not know it but, in JavaScript, whenever we interact with string, number or boolean primitives we enter a hidden world of object shadows and coercion.

string, number, boolean, null, undefined, and symbol.

In JavaScript there are 7 primitive types: `undefined`, `null`, `boolean`, `string`, `number`, `bigint` and `symbol`. Everything else is an object. The primitive types `boolean`, `string` and `number` can be wrapped by their object counterparts. These objects are instances of the `Boolean`, `String` and `Number` constructors respectively.

```
typeof true; //"boolean"
typeof new Boolean(true); //"object"

typeof "this is a string"; //"string"
typeof new String("this is a string"); //"object"

typeof 123; //"number"
typeof new Number(123); //"object"
```

If primitives have no properties, why does `"this is a string".length` return a value?

Because JavaScript will readily coerce between primitives and objects. In this case the string value is coerced to a string object in order to access the property length. The string object is only used for a fraction of second after which it is sacrificed to the Gods of garbage collection – but in the spirit of the TV discovery shows, we will trap the elusive creature and preserve it for further analysis…

To demonstrate this further consider the following example in which we are adding a new property to String constructor prototype.

```
String.prototype.sampleProperty = 5;
var str = "this is a string";
str.sampleProperty;            // 5
```

By this means primitives have access to all the properties (including methods) defined by their respective object constructors.

So we saw that primitive types will appropriately coerce to their respective Object counterpart when required.

**Analysis of `toString()` method**

Consider the following code

```
var myObj    = {lhs: 3, rhs: 2};
var myFunc   = function(){}
var myString = "This is a sample String";
var myNumber = 4;
var myArray  = [2, 3, 5];

myObj.toString();     // "[object Object]"
myFunc.toString();    // "function(){}"
myString.toString();  // "This is a sample String"
myNumber.toString();  // "4"
myArray.toString();   // "2,3,5"
```

As discussed above, what's really happening is when we call `toString()` method on a primitive type, it has to be coerced into its object counterpart before it can invoke the method.
i.e. `myNumber.toString()` is equivalent to `Number.prototype.toString.call(myNumber)` and similarly for other primitive types.

But what if instead of primitive type being passed into `toString()` method of its corresponding Object constructor function counterpart, we force the primitive type to be passed as parameter onto `toString()` method of Object function constructor (`Object.prototype.toString.call(x)`)?

**Closer look at Object.prototype.toString()**

As per the [documentation](https://es5.github.io/x15.2.html#x15.2.4.2), 
When the toString method is called, the following steps are taken:

> 1. If the `this` value is `undefined`, return `"[object Undefined]"`.
> 2. If the `this` value is `null`, return `"[object Null]"`.
> 3. If this value is none of the above, Let `O` be the result of calling [`toObject`](https://es5.github.io/x9.html#x9.9) passing the `this` value as the argument.
> 4. Let class be the value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of `O`.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings `"[object "`, `class`, and `"]"`.

Understand this from the following example

```
var myObj       = {lhs: 3, rhs: 2};
var myFunc      = function(){}
var myString    = "This is a sample String";
var myNumber    = 4;
var myArray     = [2, 3, 5];
var myUndefined = undefined;
var myNull      = null;

Object.prototype.toString.call(myObj);        // "[object Object]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(myFunc);       // "[object Function]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(myString);     // "[object String]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(myNumber);     // "[object Number]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(myArray);      // "[object Array]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(myUndefined);  // "[object Undefined]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(myNull);       // "[object Null]"
```

References:
https://es5.github.io/x15.2.html#x15.2.4.2
https://es5.github.io/x9.html#x9.9
https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/

Answer (score 13):

It's the value returned by that object's [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function.

---

I understand what you're trying to do, because I answered [your question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738040/how-do-i-toggle-between-divs/4738071#4738071) about determining which div is visible. :)
The `whichIsVisible()` function returns an actual jQuery object, because I thought that would be more *programmatically* useful. If you want to use this function for debugging purposes, you can just do something like this:

```
function whichIsVisible_v2()
{
    if (!$1.is(':hidden')) return '#1';
    if (!$2.is(':hidden')) return '#2';
}
```

That said, you **really should be using a proper debugger** rather than `alert()` if you're trying to debug a problem. If you're using Firefox, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) is excellent. If you're using IE8, Safari, or Chrome, they have built-in debuggers.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

`[object Object]` is the default string representation of a JavaScript `Object`. It is what you'll get if you run this code:

```
alert({}); // [object Object]
```

You can change the default representation by overriding the `toString` method like so:

```
var o = {toString: function(){ return "foo" }};
alert(o); // foo
```

Comment: Which is almost certainly not what he wants to do.

Comment: True, just illustrating where the `[object Object]` string came from.

Comment: You are explaining how to change the default representation, not where the original one comes from.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way out is by using `JSON.stringify()` and passing your data as param:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(whichIsVisible()));
```

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(whichIsVisible()));

Answer (score 2):

You have a javascript object

`$1` and `$2` are jquery objects, maybe use `alert($1.text());` to get text or `alert($1.attr('id');` etc...

you have to treat `$1` and `$2` like jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return an object. Because there is no good way to represent an object as a string, the object's `.toString()` value is automatically set as `"[object Object]"`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
const foo = {};
foo[Symbol.toStringTag] = "bar";
console.log("" + foo);
```

Which outputs

```
[object bar]
```

Basically, any object in javascript can define a property with the tag `Symbol.toStringTag` and override the output.

Behind the scenes construction of a new object in javascript prototypes from some object with a "toString" method. The default object provides this method as a property, and that method internally invokes the tag to determine how to coerce the object to a string. If the tag is present, then it's used, if missing you get `"Object"`.

Should you set `Symbol.toStringTag`? Maybe. But relying on the string always being `[object Object]` for "true" objects is not the best idea.

Answer (score -1):

The object whose class is Object seems quite different from the usual class instance object, because it acts like an associative array or list: it can be created by simple object literals (a list of keys and properties), like this: `let obj={A:'a',B:'b'};` and because it looks very like this same literal notation when displayed in the Developer Tools Console pane and when it is converted to a JSON string.

But, in fact, the only real difference in objects of other classes (which are derived or extended from Object) is that other classes usually have constructors and methods (these are all functions), in addition to properties (which are variables). A class instance object is allocated using the 'new' operator, and its properties and methods are accessible through the 'this' variable. You can also access the underlying static functions that are copied to each new instance by using the 'prototype' property, and even extend system classes by adding new functions to their prototype object.

The Array object is also derived from Object and is frequently used: it is an ordered, 0-indexed array of variable values.

Object objects, unlike Arrays and other classes are treated simply as associative arrays (sometimes considered ordered, and sometimes considered unordered).