# JSON.stringify returns "[object Object]" instead of the contents of the object

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

[Here I'm creating a JavaScript object and converting it to a JSON string](http://jsfiddle.net/XX2sB/), but `JSON.stringify` returns `"[object Object]"` in this case, instead of displaying the contents of the object. How can I work around this problem, so that the JSON string actually contains the contents of the object?

```
var theObject = {name:{firstName:"Mark", lastName:"Bob"}};
alert(JSON.stringify(theObject.toString())); //this alerts "[object Object]"
```

Comment: Alerts don't show objects, only strings, you should be using the console for that. And converting an object to a string does the same, you end up with [object Object], as that is the string representation of an object.

Comment: `theObject.toString()` = `"[object Object]"`

Comment: Ever wondered why [object Object] ? Have a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25419538/3001704

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify(theObject);`

Comment: how to get name from json string

Comment: @oxygen Per OP example above,  Use: `console.log(JSON.stringify(theObject.name.firstName.toString())); // output: "Mark"`

Answer (score 7):

> JSON.stringify returns "[object Object]" in this case

That is because you are calling `toString()` on the object before serializing it:

```
JSON.stringify(theObject.toString()) /* <-- here */
```

Remove the `toString()` call and it should work fine:

```
alert( JSON.stringify( theObject ) );
```

Answer (score 6):

```
theObject.toString()
```

The `.toString()` method is culprit. Remove it; and the fiddle shall work: http://jsfiddle.net/XX2sB/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var theObject = {name:{firstName:"Mark", lastName:"Bob"}};
alert(JSON.stringify(theObject));
```