# JQuery text(); returned [object Object] when retrieving information from parse object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

It seems when I am trying to retrieve information from my parse data I am having no issue displaying the information from the user table onto my document but when I try to query another object & insert it into an id element with jQuery using either text();, html();, or val(); I either get nothing or the text becomes into [object Object]. below is the code I have written down. I also tried a JavaScript method & same output I get [object Object].

```
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();



  if (currentUser) {
   var UserInfo = Parse.Object.extend("UserInfo");
   var query = new Parse.Query(UserInfo);
   query.equalTo("user", currentUser);
   query.find({
           success: function(UserInfo) {

          document.getElementById('fieldone').innerHTML = query.get("fieldone");

            $('#fieldtwo').text(query.get("fieldtwo"));

            $('#startDate').val(query.get("startdate"));

            $('#endDate').text(query.get("enddate"));
     },
        error: function(object, error) {
               }

              });

       }
```

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(query.get("fieldone")))` and see what you get..

Comment: `[object Object]` is the default result from [converting a plain `Object` to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean). If you want more information from the object, you'll have to either use something to format it differently (perhaps `JSON.stringify()`) or access the values held by its properties.

Comment: does query.get return an object or a stirng? because by default text and val() accept string for parameters so it automatically calls .toString() which for many objects just returns "[object Object"

Comment: Hello everyone thanks on speedy replies I appreciate it! So when I console log  I get {"_resolved":false,"_rejected":false,"_resolvedCallbacks":[],"_rejectedCallbacks":[]}

Answer (score 0):

`query.get` is something similar to `query.find` and returns a promise and not your data. (Notice what you logged out).

Instead of writing `query.get("fieldtwo")`, you should be writing `UserInfo[i].get("fieldtwo")` because the queried data is present in the returned `UserInfo` object, after the `success` callback is resolved.

Your code should look like:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();



  if (currentUser) {
   var UserInfo = Parse.Object.extend("UserInfo");
   var query = new Parse.Query(UserInfo);
   query.equalTo("user", currentUser);
   query.find({
           success: function(UserInfo) {

    for(var i = 0 ; i < UserInfo.length; ++i)
    {
       var mydata = UserInfo[i].get("fieldone");
       // do anything with mydata
     }

     },
        error: function(object, error) {
               }

              });

       }
```

Comment: when I give it a try I receive UserInfo.get is not a function

Comment: @ErickFunes, My fault. I have corrected it. Please see the edit. In short, you just have to do `UserInfo[index].get("fieldone")`.