# Show values of [object Object] data

Tags: javascript, php, object

I got data from third party plugin and I just got `[object Object]` in javascript. I want to pass it on `PHP` and show all the values on that `[object Object]`. How could I to do that ? I already pass it to `PHP` through `GET`

I got this `[object Object]` from this part.

```
widget.createButton()
    .attr('title', "Save chart")
    .on('click', function (e) {
    widget.save(function(data) {
        window.location.href = "temp.php?var=" + data;
    })
})
.append($('<span>save chart</span>'));
```

This is my `PHP` code.

```
<?php

$var = $_GET['var'];

var_dump($var);
exit();

?>
```

if I do `var_dump` it still get `[object Object]` but I want to get the values of that `[object Object]`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you get `[object Object]`

Comment: see this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal I already edit my question.

Comment: @Suchitkumar I already edit my question. I want to show all the values from `PHP` code not inside `javascript`.

Comment: try:`"temp.php?var=" +JSON.stringify(data);` and use `json_decode($_GET['var'],true);` in php and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object is being converted to a string. Try this in a browser console to see.

```
var a = {}
a.toString() // this will give you [object Object]
```

In your code at this step:

```
window.location.href = "temp.php?var=" + data;
```

you are converting data from `object` to `string`. You need to do this

```
window.location.href = "temp.php?var=" + JSON.stringify(data);
```

and on PHP part of the code, you will now receive it as string, so you need to do this:

```
$var = var_dump(json_decode($_GET['var']));
```

Comment: if I convert it from `object` to `string` with `JSON.stringify(data)` the URI of `temp.php?var=" + JSON.stringify(data)` is too large.

Comment: because of that I want convert it in `PHP` after it pass through `GET`.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use a get request for it. What you need to understand is, `[object Object]` no longer contains your actual object data and cannot be converted back. Just look at the first code snippet, even `{}` looks like `[object Object]` it is just a way of saying an object got converted to a string.

Comment: @Antonio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request please refer to this to see why you can't send more data.

Comment: and what should I do to pass it if `GET` cannot pass that data ?

Comment: use https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ or http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php to make a `POST` request.