# Get the name of [object Object] using 'this'

Tags: javascript, object

I´m working with a software where I don't know the global object name(no, it´s not window), but I want to.

```
console.log(this)
```

gives me [object object]

```
for(var property in this) {
    console.log(property + "=" + this.property);
}
```

gives me the properties of 'this'.

However, I need the name/id(something with what I could access the properties in another contexts/objects) of 'this'. Is it somehow possible to get that?

I already [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean) for this, but couldn´t find a fitting solution.

Comment: Objects don't have names?

Comment: Please post your complete code @Faizy

Comment: @Liam they do if they are created using a Constructor function or the new ES6 class syntax.

Comment: @WilomGfx: functions have names, objects do not.

Comment: `var someName = this;`?

Comment: What like `Barry` or `Chris`? :D

Comment: @FelixKling i am aware of that, but an object created from a Constructor or the new ES6 class syntax will.

Comment: @WilomGfx: Can you link to the spec where this is described?

Comment: Objects don't have "names". `a = {}; b = a;`  Is this object's "name" a or b?   Anyway, you can use `this.prop` or `this['prop']` and you can assign the value of `this` like any other variable `thing = this; thing.prop = something`

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, that´s a nice workaround. Didn´t think of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the property value from `this` context using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

```
for(property in this) {
    console.log(property + "=" + this[property]);
    //                       ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----
}
```

---

You can get the object properties using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method which returns the array of property names.

---

**FYI :** To access `this` context within an another context refers it using a variable which has scope within both contexts(commonly you can use a global variable).

```
// initial variable or neglect to make it as global
var self;

/* cotext 1 start */

// define   
self = this;

for(property in self) {
    console.log(property + "=" + self[property]);
}
/* cotext 1 end  */

/* cotext 2 start */

// use `self` to refer the context1         
for(property in self) {
    console.log(property + "=" + self[property]);
} 

/* cotext 2 end  */
```

Comment: Also, a bad alternative is `JSON.stringify`. Or `console.log("%O", this);` or `console.log("%o", this);`.

Comment: Sorry, i meant it like the way you wrote it. My mistake. Thank you.

Comment: While this clearly a mistake in the OP's code, I don't think that's what they are asking about.