# What does the syntax of [object Object] actually mean?

Tags: javascript

Converting a JS object to a string returns `[object Object]`.

So I understand that `[object Object]` is the default string representation of a JavaScript object, but I still don't understand what any of that syntax is. It just looks like a comma-less array to me. What do the brackets mean? Why is 'object' written inside of the brackets twice, and capitalized once?

*In response to duplication concerns: Other questions about [object Object] only ask what it **is**. I understand that `[object Object]` is the string representation of a JS object. I am asking specifically about the meaning of the syntax here.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25419538/101087

Comment: It's not anything specific. It does not represent any JS literal syntax. Anything else would have worked - `{davids Object}`. `[object …]` is just they way they chose.