# Angular application fails to load data from Flask server and instead displays a weird message

Tags: angularjs, flask

I am running my Angular application with Brackets' Live Preview. Once the page index.html loads I get the following message on the web browser: "127.0.0.1:50894 [object Object]".

The index.html file is:

```
<html ng-app="dbsysApp">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>


        <h2><a ng-href="/"> <span class="label label-primary">Home </span></a></h2>


        <div ng-view></div>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/homeController.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I am not really sure what other information you may need. If you require to know something else, please tell me.

If you are familiar with this message or what it means I would appreciate your help.

Comment: There is a similar question it Explains what [object Object] is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean

Comment: Thank you. I did check that answer before but it does not solve my problem.