# why getting error [object][object] when passing variable in alert

Tags: javascript

```
 function brands(id)
 {

   var brand_id = $("#brands").val(id); //id is also getting here
   alert(brand_id);    // but not show in the alert box
 }
```

why to show the the localhost say [object][object] there are no any result getting to me.

Comment: What's the #brands element?

Comment: Try `console.log(brand_id)` and see in browser console what you are getting as output.

Comment: Precisely what result are you expecting the alert to be displaying? And, could you please also include the markup for the `#brands` element in your question? – But, `[object Object]` means that [`brand_id` is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean), which `alert()` forces to a string.

Comment: ok we are resolve it.now getting id

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#brands").val(id)
```

You are assigning value and not reading value from it, also`.val(<with param>)` returns `jQuery's object` for the given DOM element, hence when you use `alert()` you get `[object object]`. Use `brand_id.val()`, you will get the expected results.

```js
$(function() {
  var v1 = $('#t1').val('hi');
  alert(v1); /* jquery object */
  alert(v1.val()); /* actual value */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="t1" />
```