# object Object convert to json object

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I have a response from a third party api as [object Object] now I want to parse the value of this object but not able to do that using JSOn.parse. Any idea how can I get the properties of object in JavaScript?

Comment: What happens when you do JSON.parse() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does \[object Object\] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean)

Comment: @jrook it's not duplicate as the responses doesn't tell about how to get the values properties from object.

Comment: Json.parse returns only bracket [

Comment: I didn't see any difference with the question I linked. Please edit your question to clearly state your problem, possibly with code samples and the steps you have taken so far to resolve the issue. You can also consult this guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: The question is clear I just want to get the properties of an object if you have the answer then provide the appropriate link.The one you provide doesn't have the answer.i Don't think any code is required because the question is simple and is understood by others.

Comment: @iAviator can you post your JSON value in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Below will help you out to iterator through each Key-item of your any depth data in javascript. This is for properties.

```
<script>

    var obj = {
    lang: "php",
    popularity: "80",
    complexity: {
        syntax: "simple",
        oop: "supported",
                    orm:"available",
                    desktop:false
    }
}

for(var propt in obj){            

        if (typeof(obj[propt]) === 'object'){
              myIterator(obj[propt]);      
        }else{
            alert(propt + ': ' + obj[propt]);
        }             
}

    function myIterator(myData){            
        for(var propt in myData){            
            alert(propt + ': ' + myData[propt]);            
            if (typeof(myData[propt]) === 'object'){
              myIterator(myData[propt]);      
            } 
        }            
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: It is too complex.Isn't there any vanilla js method that return all the properties of an object?

Comment: above is concept understanding on basics for Framework based solution you should go through below articles hope that will help you  https://codybonney.com/how-to-iterate-over-an-object-in-javascript/                                    and  http://www.competa.com/blog/loop-object-vanilla-javascript/