# Output of object in console failed

Tags: javascript

I've a simple question for learning javascript.

I create an array with objects like this

```
var myresult =new Array(); [];
for (i= 2015;i<=2030;i=i+1)
{
      var newobject={'myname' : i};
      myresult.push(newobject);
}
console.log ('Result:'+myresult);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myresult));
```

In Console I see this output

```
Result:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

[{"myname":2015},{"myname":2016},{"myname":2017},{"myname":2018},{"myname":2019},{"myname":2020},{"myname":2021},{"myname":2022},{"myname":2023},{"myname":2024},{"myname":2025},{"myname":2026},{"myname":2027},{"myname":2028},{"myname":2029},{"myname":2I30}]
```

**Why cant I see it in this way?**
[image]

Comment: Because `({"myname":2015}).toString()` is `"[object Object]"` and not `'{"myname":2015}'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does \[object Object\] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean)

Comment: Try [`console.dir(myresult)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir)

Comment: @SurajRao Logging `myresult` itself works. That’s not the question. The OP is concatenating objects to a string, thus coercing everything to a string.

Comment: @Xufox From the question it looked like OP wanted to print it in the interactive way `dir` does...OP will have to clarify

Comment: In any case, if you don’t want to coerce objects, you should write `console.log("Result:", myresult);` or `console.log("Result:%o", myresult);`.

Comment: in wich way i have to change my code that i get a output like the image in my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used string concatenation, which stringifies the object as JSON. Use

```
console.log('Result:', myresult);
```

instead.

**EDIT:** I just tried this in Firefox Javascript console:

```
>> const myresult = [];
undefined

>> const newobject = {'myname': 1};
undefined

>> console.log('NEWOBJECT:', newobject);
NEWOBJECT: Object { myname: 1 }
debugger eval code:1:1
undefined

>> myresult.push(newobject);
1

>> console.log('MYRESULT:', myresult);
MYRESULT: Array [ {…} ]
debugger eval code:1:1
undefined
```

i.e. logging the object works fine.

Comment: may i do something wrong by creating the array and objects? I want to have a output of my array with object like the image in my post ...

Comment: Have you tried `console.log('NEWOBJECT:', newobject)`?

Comment: thats all? The output is now like in the picture, so i think my way to define array and objects is correctly - thanks a lot @Stefan Becker