# How to fix [object Object] Javascript error?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, methods, get

I would like to display a request from my JSON placeholder. I'm unsure where to start or even what is the right question to ask to resolve my error.

I understand why the error occurs as shown here ([what does [object Object] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean)) I don't understand how to fix the problem. I know I would need to use console.log() but unsure how to return the specific values to a variable then display it on the screen.

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Click here to execute your first Ajax get request</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", function(title, completed){
      alert("Title: " + title + "\nCompleted: " + completed);
    });
  });
});
```

Expected result

```
  "Title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": success
```

Answer (score 1):

***title*** is an *object*, it is not the property you are thinking. You have to access the *title* property from ***title*** *object*.

Try `title.title`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", function(title, completed){
      alert("Title: " + title.title + "\nCompleted: " + completed);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Click here to execute your first Ajax get request</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check example on https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/. Which shows that it returns the object rather than the single value. Example can be illustrated as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.btn', function(){
   $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", function(result_object, completed){
     console.log(result_object);
     alert("Title: " + result_object.title + "\nCompleted: " + completed);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Click here to execute your first Ajax get request</button>
```