# Jquery Ajax request returning data in Array format data[0]....data[100]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The issue I am having is that when I am sending an Ajax request, I am getting data, but in Array if I have to look in to the data I have to do data[0]....data[100] I want to convert this data in model so I can pass this to my MVC model or directly pass to my DevExtrem Controller

**Jquery**

```
function getPowerSpecialtyId(GirdObject) {
    debugger;
    debugger;
    var BenchMarkId = GirdObject.data ? [GirdObject.data.BenchmarkSurveyId] : null;

    if (BenchMarkId != null) {
        var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
        var geturl = baseurl + "/Service/Request/BCD?selectedSurveyId=" + BenchMarkId;
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: geturl,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);


            },
            error: function (data) {
                DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert("Couldn't fetch details try again", "Oops!");
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        null;
    }
    null;
}
```

**Alert showing this** 
[image]

```
object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[
```

[image]

[image]

C# model

```
  public class BDTO
    {

        public int BId { get; set; }
        public int PId { get; set; }
        public int BkSId { get; set; }      
        public string SName { get; set; }
    }
```

is it away i can converst everything in Model list so i can get list like?

example  List 
BId: a, PId:s BkSId:2  SName:3 
BId: 1a, PId:1s BkSId:22  SName:23

so i can easily pass this to c# model

**console.log(data)**
[image]

Comment: This will tell you why you are getting `[object Object]` in your alert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean

Comment: Could you tell us how you'd want the data to look?

also, you should output for debuging using `console.log()`

Comment: Chrome splits them up so as to appear as separate array to make manual traversal easier (I assume), but in reality, all of your elements are in a single array.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks let me check

Comment: @GijsBeijer I need data in List as i have a Model BDTO

Comment: I think you are getting it in a (js) similar way. Outputting it with an alert will only show you the types of objects, if you'd output the data using `console.log()` you'd see the actual data in your console.

Comment: @GijsBeijer console.log() check the image is it possible we can convert this in a BDTO

Comment: What does BDTO mean?

Comment: It's an array of objects, each object has properties `BId`, `PId`, `BkSId`, and `SName`. You can access all those properties using normal object notation, e.g. `data[i].BId`.

Comment: Thats exactly what you got there, the browser shows your array in parts (so you can expand them more easily.

You should be able to call one of the items as `data[i]` and also the properties using dot notation.

so leaves us with what @Barmar says: what does BDTO mean?

Comment: you will have to iterate over it and then pass it back to the service as an object

Comment: or an array of objects