# In react with hooks, how to append to a state to create a history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I'm still learning react, so this may just be because I don't fully understand what I'm doing yet.
The formattedText field is just a temporary text that the user creates from a button click.  I want to create a running history of this field, so I created historyText.

```
function App() {
  const [formattedText, setFormattedText] = useState([]);
  const [historyText, setHistoryText] = useState([]);
```

In my button click action, I'm setting the formattedText:

```
setFormattedText(tempComp);
```

And I thought I could just append it to my history:

```
setHistoryText(historyText+tempComp);
```

But it doesn't work, all I get is `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` as my output.

** Clarification: the reason this may look strange because I'm storing html in the strings and wanted it to show as html.  Here's how I'm building tempComp:

```
tempComp.push(<p><b>{dResult[y].dp5}</b></p>);
```

Different lines are formatted differently, so I couldn't just use a split to add in a `<p>` for example.

Comment: Can we see other parts of your component, please?

Comment: Use `setHistoryText([...historyText, tempComp]);` (this will append the value to the array)

Comment: @ChrisG, your suggestion worked. Now its showing a running log of what I want. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate instead, since it is :) (I didn't downvote though)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, ou are not using `String` values but an `Object` and the default string representation of an object is just `[object Object]`. I'm not totally sure, what you want to add to read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean).

```
setHistoryText(historyText+tempComp);
```

but maybe try to `console.log` the objects out first, and see if maybe you where meant to access an attribute instead

```
//other logic
console.log(historyText) //do you mean to access a value on the object instead?
console.log(tempComp)
setHistoryText(historyText+tempComp);
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, you haven't fixed the OP's code. Explaining what the problem is isn't enough, you need to show how to fix it.

Comment: well without more information, and can't be fixed.

Comment: My comment fixed it for OP, and it's a dupe anyway. So how can't this be fixed...?