# Angular 8 Show HTTP response with the right data. ([object Object])

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, angular8

In my current Angular project I send a JSON file to a server and the server gives me back a modified JSON file. The new JSON file should be displayed in a tree.

My current problem is that I cannot read the data from the new JSON. Whenever I want to display a JSON Object, I always get the error:

```
[object Object]
```

Post request:

```
public sendJSON() {
    this.http.post('url', this.combineJSON,{headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}).subscribe((data: Device) => {

    console.log("Test Output: " + data);
  })
}
```

I defined a model to work with the response:

```
export class Device {
    orderNumber: number;

    deviceTypeId: number;

    swRevision: string;

    hwRevision: string;
}
```

Where is the problem here that the data is not displayed correctly?

Comment: `console.log("Test Output: ",  data)`

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON Object. It's either JSON, i.e. text, or an Object. To see proper console output, use `console.log("Test Output: ", data);`

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to print a whole object. You can utilize `JSON.stringify()` function to display your object as a string.

```js
console.log("Test Output: " + JSON.stringify(data));
```

The model you defined helps you to identify all properties of data object in your source code.
As an example you could print the `swRevision` property with:

```js
console.log("Test Output: " + data.swRevision);
```

Answer (score 3):

The data not being correctly displayed is because of the `+` in your console.log.

`+` concatenates strings and, in the case of something other than a string, calls the `toString()` method of the object.

Simply change:

```
console.log("Test Output: " + data);
```

to:

```
console.log("Test Output: ", data);
```

and it should display your object.