# JavaScript Object output

Tags: javascript

I am confused by JS object output.

First one:

```js
var a = {}
console.log(a);
```

the output for the first one is `{}`.

Second one:

```js
var a = {}
console.log(a + '123');
```

the output for the second one is `[object Object]123`

Third one:

```js
var a = {
  toString: function() {
    return 'hello'
  }
}
console.log(a + '123');
```

the output for the third one is `hello123`

I don't understand why the second one is `[object Object]123` while the third one is `hello123`

Comment: console.log(a + '123'); => this means, convert a and '123' to string. in third sample you defined a toString method, that will be used to convert your object in string.

Comment: because in #2 you are combining an object and a string where as in #3 you overrode the toString function of the object with a function that returns hello. When you combine with a string js is automatically calling the toString method on the object.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean

Comment: my take on this.. console.log(a); should actually return Object { } (meaning empty object). if you do console.log(a.toString()); it will become "[object Object]", which is why if you do console.log(a + 123), the a becomes a.toString() and 123 also becomes string, you will get [obejct Object]123. when you override the original  Object toString() method to return 'hello', now the a.toString() = hello, hence you will get the hello123

Comment: Try `var a = {} console.log(a.toString());`  The toString happens implicitly in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the part you're missing is that Objects already have a default toString() method, and its implementation returns `[object Object]`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Answer (score 0):

- In the first example the value of the object at the moment you open the console is displayed
- In the second example, the `toString` method inside the `Object` prototype is called on the object because of concatenation(+) with a string, which converts the object to string and concatenates the result to '123', note that when calling `toString` to an object it just gives you `[object Object]`.
- In the third example, `toString` is again called on the object due to concatenation(+) with a string. The object has, however, overridden the `toString` method definition in the prototype by a custom `toString` method 
  that returns 'hello', so it will concatenate 'hello' to '123'. Without the custom `toString` function definition it would have looked the function up in the prototype chain and would have printed `[object Object]` like the second example.