# JavaScript ouput of an array with multiple values shows the words "object, object"

Tags: javascript

```
var dynastyReign = [ 
{"San Dynasty": "MXLI"},
{"Viloria Dynasty": "MCCCIIII"},
{"Tan Dynasty": "MCCCXCVIII"},  
{"Bon Dynasty": "MCDXLV"},   
{"Maiko Dynasty": "MDCLXIV"}, 
{"Paul Dynasty": "MCMXLIX"},
{"Andre Dynasty": "MMMXICX"}
];

document.write(dynastyReign.toString());
```

I tried to output this array with two values on each one using toString, but the output only gives me `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`.

How do I stop the object word from showing, and if possible i would also like only the roman numeral part shown, removing the "Dynasty".

Comment: Write a loop that prints each object the way you want it.

Comment: The easiest method is likely to use “JSON.stringify”. The other operation can be done with a transform of the original data.

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean. You need to convert the object to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dynastyReign = [ 
  {"San Dynasty": "MXLI"},
  {"Viloria Dynasty": "MCCCIIII"},
  {"Tan Dynasty": "MCCCXCVIII"},  
  {"Bon Dynasty": "MCDXLV"},   
  {"Maiko Dynasty": "MDCLXIV"}, 
  {"Paul Dynasty": "MCMXLIX"},
  {"Andre Dynasty": "MMMXICX"}
];

var text = dynastyReign.map(d => Object.values(d)[0])
document.write(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dynastyReign = [ 
{"San Dynasty": "MXLI"},
{"Viloria Dynasty": "MCCCIIII"},
{"Tan Dynasty": "MCCCXCVIII"},  
{"Bon Dynasty": "MCDXLV"},   
{"Maiko Dynasty": "MDCLXIV"}, 
{"Paul Dynasty": "MCMXLIX"},
{"Andre Dynasty": "MMMXICX"}
];

//document.write(dynastyReign.toString());

document.write(JSON.stringify(dynastyReign).replace(/Dynasty/g,''));

console.log(JSON.stringify(dynastyReign).split('Dynasty').join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dynastyReign.map(reign => Object.values(reign)[0]).join(', ');`