# How to return object from Asynchronous call in NodeJS? Returning Object from callback [object Object]

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, require

Trying to get a single object returned by request using callbacks.
[image: Callback]

Error:undefined
Data:[object Object]
Why are there two objects being returned when I am returning only one error and one object?

Comment: Instead of undefined, please send `null`.

Comment: @MihirKumar Sending a error as null when there is no error.Callback prints null.
But I am not getting the object.
Error:null
Data:[object Object]
Didn't get it. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Instead of null everywhere you need to use null & JSON.stringify the data you are sending and then JSON.parse it again in geoCode

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.  When you post it as an image, it won't be indexed for search, people trying to write answers can't copy your code into an answer and fix/modify it and its much harder to deal with on mobile devices.  Please post code as text.

Comment: I tried formatting,there were too many indentation errors. I moved a few spaces and the code was not readable.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is only one object being returned from the callback. The reason why `[object Object]` is printed, is because that is the default serialization of an object.

You can see this answer for a detailed explanation:
[what does [object Object] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25419538/11389917)

To print the data contained in the object, you can `JSON.stringify` it like this:

```js
    console.log("Data:"+JSON.stringify(data))
```