# I want to convert JSON stringify Data into an associative array?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, reactjs

I retrieved the data from the database which was in `[object Object]`.

I usually convert these data using `JSON.parse` but it did not working so, I tried `JSON.stringify` but the data now it's like

`[{"station" : "NewYork"}, {"station" : "Toronto"}]`

Now I don't know how to convert this data into an array object and access it. I need only object entries but I don't know how to access it.

If it is declared to `var data` I need it like `data[0]['station']` to access but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Try `data[0]['station']` without `JSON.stringify` or `JSON.parse`

Comment: No, Initially it's in this format [{object Object},{object Object}] so I converted, I tried even your method it's showing undefined.

Comment: `[object object]` is default serialization of an object. [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25419538/2873538)

Comment: `I retrieved the data from the database`: How? From an API response? How does your API respose look in browser? It should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlyCE.png).

Comment: I'm getting a response like `{"message":[{"station_name":"Hebbal"},{"station_name":"Jalahalli"},{"station_name":"Malleshwaram"},{"station_name":"Peenya"},{"station_name":"R.T.Nagar"},{"station_name":"Rajajinagar"}]}` @AjeetShah

Comment: It looks in correct, JSON, format. Now show us code where you are trying to access it. You can add that in your question by editing it.