# jquery iterate json variable with $.each gives me a result of [object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I try to get a json var into HTML, as you see in the snippet the result is [object]

Why do I get this [object] result?

Note: I want to iterate true the json dynamically, because the next json export may be completely different, I might add a extra field or I might remove 'ISO' etc.

```js
var json = [{
    "SourceFile": "/Volumes/Ext 1TB/Google Drive/temp/test1/MapA/2019-10-15 13,46,54 Panasonic-DMC-TZ20.JPG",
    "FileName": "2019-10-15 13,46,54 Panasonic-DMC-TZ20.JPG",
    "FileSize": "5.0 MB",
    "Model": "DMC-TZ20",
    "DateTimeOriginal": "2019:10:15 13:46:54",
    "ImageSize": "4320x2880",
    "FocalLength": "4.3 mm",
    "ShutterSpeed": "1/25",
    "Aperture": 3.3,
    "ISO": 200,
    "WhiteBalance": "Cloudy",
    "Flash": "Off, Did not fire"
  },
  {
    "SourceFile": "/Volumes/Ext 1TB/Google Drive/temp/test1/MapA/2019-10-15 13,51,08 Panasonic-DMC-FZ2000.JPG",
    "FileName": "2019-10-15 13,51,08 Panasonic-DMC-FZ2000.JPG",
    "FileSize": "4.8 MB",
    "Model": "DMC-FZ2000",
    "DateTimeOriginal": "2019:10:15 13:51:08",
    "ImageSize": "3840x2160",
    "FocalLength": "175.7 mm",
    "ShutterSpeed": "1/125",
    "Aperture": 4.5,
    "ISO": 160,
    "WhiteBalance": "Cloudy",
    "Flash": "Off, Did not fire"
  },
  {
    "SourceFile": "/Volumes/Ext 1TB/Google Drive/temp/test1/MapA/2019-10-15 13,52,39 Panasonic-DMC-FZ2000.JPG",
    "FileName": "2019-10-15 13,52,39 Panasonic-DMC-FZ2000.JPG",
    "FileSize": "4.0 MB",
    "Model": "DMC-FZ2000",
    "DateTimeOriginal": "2019:10:15 13:52:39",
    "ImageSize": "3840x2160",
    "FocalLength": "34.7 mm",
    "ShutterSpeed": "1/160",
    "Aperture": 4.1,
    "ISO": 125,
    "WhiteBalance": "Cloudy",
    "Flash": "Off, Did not fire"
  }
];
console.log(json);
$.each(json, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key + ": " + value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Exif test</h1>
<p>I want something like this:<br> each json entry must show here, all the fields are variable.
</p>
<p>
  SourceFile: /Volumes/Ext 1TB/Google Drive/temp/test1/MapA/2019-10-15 13,52,39 Panasonic-DMC-FZ2000.JPG<br> FileName : 2019-10-15 13,52,39 Panasonic-DMC-FZ2000.JPG <br> FileSize : 4.0 MB <br> etc. etc.

</p>
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/4750225?

Comment: the `key` parameter will be the index of the array item. The `value` parameter will be the item that is stored in this index which in your case is always an object.If you want to store it as a JSON string you can use the `stringify()` function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your loop as follow.

```
$.each(json, function(keyIndex, valueObject) {
 $.each(valueObject, (key, value)=>(console.log(key,":" ,value)));
})
```