# Display the value of the id of the event with eventclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to get the id of the event in order to remove the event from the database. I am trying to get the id with eventClick, when user clicks an event, pops up a dialog and asks user to remove the event. To do that, I need the id of the event.

**But when I get it with "info.event.id", it returns [object Object] and cannot get it properly.**

```
eventClick = (info) => {
    this.setState({
      eventId: info.event.id, // returns [object Object]
      title: info.event.title,
      start: info.event.start.toString(),
      end: info.event.end.toString(),
    });
```

This is the console.log(info.event) output:

```
EventApi {_calendar: Calendar, _def: {…}, _instance: {…}}
allDay: (...)
allow: (...)
backgroundColor: (...)
borderColor: (...)
classNames: (...)
constraint: (...)
durationEditable: (...)
end: Fri Jun 12 2020 17:01:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
extendedProps: (...)
groupId: (...)
id: "[object Object]"
overlap: (...)
rendering: (...)
source: EventSourceApi
start: Thu Jun 11 2020 17:01:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
```

Every object except id display well. How do I get it real value of the id?

Btw, I already tried the `JSON.stringify()`, it could not work. Also, the object is not a JSON object. It is a random integer like "3525".

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say maybe you supplied the ID to fullCalendar incorrectly in the first place, perhaps by stringifying an object. But it's hard to know without more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have object type [object object] in that 'id' key, maybe try using

`JSON.stringify(info.event.id)` and then find the exact id value you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it gets an error when `JSON.stringify({info.event.id})`, it accepts `JSON.stringify(info.event.id)` and it still renders "[object Object]"

Comment: Can you provide the full console output?

Comment: Sure. `EventApi {_calendar: Calendar, _def: {…}, _instance: {…}}
allDay: false
allow: null
backgroundColor: ""
borderColor: ""
classNames: Array(0)
constraint: null
durationEditable: null
end: Fri Jun 12 2020 17:01:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
extendedProps: Object
groupId: ""
id: "[object Object]"
overlap: null
rendering: ""
source: EventSourceApi
start: Thu Jun 11 2020 17:01:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
startEditable: null
textColor: ""
title: "test3"
url: ""  `

Comment: Remaining `_calendar: Calendar {buildComponentContext: ƒ, parseRawLocales: ƒ, buildLocale: ƒ, buildDateEnv: ƒ, buildTheme: ƒ, …}
_def:
allDay: false
defId: "6"
extendedProps: {}
groupId: ""
hasEnd: true
publicId: "[object Object]"
rendering: ""
sourceId: "5"
title: "test3"
ui: {startEditable: null, durationEditable: null, constraints: Array(0), overlap: null, allows: Array(0), …}
url: ""
__proto__: Object
_instance: {instanceId: "7", defId: "6", range: {…}, forcedStartTzo: null, forcedEndTzo: null}
__proto__: Object`

Comment: So by some chance is the `id` key in `info.event` being converted to String because the ouptut you're getting is suggesting that `id` is containing an object definitely that's why its showing that [object object], you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/25419538/3001704 for understanding this.