# Jquery to retrieve multiple keys with same starting pattern from LocalStorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage, keyvaluepair

Consider I'm storing 5 datas using `localStorage.setItem()`:

{"abc1":"yes",
"abc2":"yes",
"abc3":"yes",
"uvw":"no",
"xyz":"no"}

For retrieving we can use `localStorage.getItem()`. But here I need to retrieve all the key value pairs whose key name starts with the string "abc" i.e. to retrieve keys `"abc1"`, `"abc2"` and `"abc3"`.

This is what i tried :

```
var a = {}, 
keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
l = keys.length;
        
while (l--) { 
  a[keys[l]] = localStorage.getItem(keys[l]);
  if(a[keys[l]].startsWith('abc') == "true") {
    alert(a[keys[l]]);
  }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Are those really 5 different local storage items, or did you store one item with the JSON encoding of that object?

Comment: @Barmar It's 5 different items

Comment: `startsWith()` doesn't return a string. It returns the boolean `true` or `false`.

Comment: Just write `if(a[keys[l]].startsWith('abc'))` without the `== "true"` comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. `startsWith()` returns a boolean, not a string.
2. You're checking whether the *value* begins with `abc`, not the key.

```
var a = {};
Object.entries(localStorage).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (key.startsWith("abc")) {
    a[key] = value;
  }
});
console.log(a);
```

Comment: I didn't get what i wanted. I can see only [object Object].

Comment: I don't think any of my code would cause that. That will happen if you tried to store objects in local storage without converting them to JSON first.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like:

```
var a = {},
  keys = Object.keys(localStorage);

$.each(keys, function(i, k) {
  if (k.startsWith("abc")) {
    a[k] = localStorage[k];
  }
});

console.log(a);
```

**Test Example**

```js
var local = {
  "abc1": "yes",
  "abc2": "yes",
  "abc3": "yes",
  "uvw": "no",
  "xyz": "no"
};
var a = {},
  keys = Object.keys(local);

$.each(keys, function(i, k) {
  if (k.startsWith("abc")) {
    a[k] = local[k];
  }
});

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This results in a new Object with just the Key Value pairs expected.

**Alternate**

```js
var local = {
  "abc1": "yes",
  "abc2": "yes",
  "abc3": "yes",
  "uvw": "no",
  "xyz": "no"
};
var a = {};

$.each(local, function(k, v) {
  if (k.startsWith("abc")) {
    a[k] = v;
  }
});

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```