# how to display an object in a tooltip in a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table, datatable

I create a table dynamically with data coming from an ajax response 
I want to display data stored in an object in a tooltip anchored to the cell.
For the moment I manage to display my table but this one displays `[object Object]`.
What I want to do is display in element 0 of this object and display the rest in the tooltip.

[Run with jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/267tgqkv/2/)

**Here is my datasource**

```
var response=  {
  "service1": {
    "APH7": "1.1.5",
    "USE1": "1.1.5",
    "EUW1": "1.1.5",
    "APK2": {
      "CSTG": "1.0.10",
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": "1.0.10"
    },
    "APT2": {
      "CSTG": "1.1.5",
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": "1.1.5"
    },
    "INDW2": {
      "CSTG": "1.1.5",
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": "1.1.5"
    },
    "USW1": {
      "CSTG": "1.1.5",
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": "1.1.5"
    },
    "USW2": {
      "CSTG": "1.1.5",
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": "1.1.5"
    },
    "AP2": {
      "CSTG": "1.1.5",
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": "1.1.5"
    },
    "APS2": {
      "CSTG": "1.1.5",
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": "1.1.5"
    },
    "0": "CD"
  },
  "service2": {
    "APH7": 1,
    "EUW1": 1,
    "USE1": 1,
    "APS2": {
      "CSTG": 1,
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": 1
    },
    "USW2": {
      "CSTG": 1,
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": 1
    },
    "USW1": {
      "prd": "1",
      "CSTH200722": null,
      "0": 1
    },
    "APK2": {
      "CSTG": 1,
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": 1
    },
    "APT2": {
      "CSTG": 1,
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": 1
    },
    "AP2": {
      "CSTG": 1,
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": 1
    },
    "INDW2": {
      "CSTG": 1,
      "CSTH": null,
      "0": 1
    },
    "0": "BSF"
  }
}
```

**Table rendering display function**

```
function rendertable(data){

  //data from webservice
  var dataSet = data;

  //create table
  var table  = $("#deploymentMap_table").DataTable({
    data: constructRaws(dataSet),//tbody
    paging:   false,
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    responsive: false,
    dom: 't', //display only the table
    order: [[ 0, 'asc' ]],//order by 'service' col
    columnDefs:[
    {
      targets:'_all', 
      render:function(data){
        if(data == null) {return ""
      } else {return data;}
  }

  },
    // hide type column
    { targets: 1, "visible": false},
    { targets: 0, "width" : "200px"},

    ],
    columns: constructColumns(dataSet),//thead 

    // attribute classname (background color) for services
    rowCallback: function(row, data, index){
      if(data[0] != "CD"){$(row).find('td:eq(0)').css('background-color', '#2f6fa6').css('color', '#fff');
      }
      else{
        $(row).find('td:eq(0)').css('background-color', '#ff961f').css('color', '#fff');
      }
  },

    // generate tooltip and td style
    createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex) {

      $.each(row.childNodes, function(i,value){

        if(value.innerHTML == 1){
          value.innerHTML = "BSF"
        }
        else if(value.innerHTML == 2){
          value.innerHTML = "PATH1"
        }

        if( i != 0){
          if(value.innerHTML){
            $(value).addClass('td_color');
            $(value).attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip').attr('title', '<div align="left">Service : '+data['service']+'<br>version : '+value.innerHTML+'<br>Type :'+data[0]+'</di>');
          }
        }
      })
    },
  });
function constructRaws(data) {
  var raws = [];
  $.each(data, function(i, value) {
      
      // This code is used to display item 0 of the object
      // If I do this my object is destroyed,
      // and becomes unusable to display it in the tooltip
      //***********************************************
      //$.each(value, function(ind, val){
          // if (typeof val === "object"){
              //value[ind] = val[0];
          //} 
      //});
      //
      raws.push($.extend(value, {service: i}));   
  });
  return raws;
}

function constructColumns(data) {
 
  var regions = [];
  //get all regions
  $.each(data, function(i,service) {
    $.each(service, function(region) {
      regions.push(region);
    });  
  });
  regions = $.unique(regions.sort()) ;

  var columns = [];
  //set default columns 
  columns.push({data : 'service', title: 'Services'});

  //set regions columns
  $.each(regions, function(i,value) {
    if(value != "service"){
      columns.push({data: value, title: value });
    }
  });
  return  columns;
}
```

**Currently the rendering is this one**
[image]

**And I would like it to be here**
[image]

I don't know if the code I produced is the best one to make my table, thank you for your help.

Thanks

Comment: If you're seeing `[Object object]` then you're outputting an object rather than a string, this is essentially (not js code) `convert_to_string(object)` which gives `[Object object]`.  See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57310111/2181514  (doesn't appear to be a duplicate, just more info on Object object)

Comment: Can you please convert your code to Code snippet or use external resource like https://jsfiddle.net so it will be easier for us to point the problem. Thanks

Comment: sorry, here is the link to jsfiddle.net : https://jsfiddle.net/267tgqkv/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, I added a function which will read the object then I inject in the construction of the line the data.
The result is in the Jsfiddle