# what does this error mean, I could not understand '[1006/094704.464:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR [object Object]"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

This error appears in my cmd when I run my python scraper code. my code tries to scrape a website using selenium, this error continuously appears when my code tries to get some content.

This question is just for clearing my doubt why I am getting this.

```
[1006/094704.464:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR [object Object]", source: https://example.com/token-assets/8e3b439bc40554e4bcb656864e9a1324/main.js (1)
[1006/094705.880:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR [object Object]", source: https://example.com/token-assets/8e3b439bc40554e4bcb656864e9a1324/main.js (1)
full <section class="ng-star-inserted" id="description"><!-- --><h2 class="sam-ui header"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- -->Description<!-- --><!-- --></h2><!-- --><!-- --><div class="sam-ui hidden section divider"></div></section>
outD = None
 div = 1 page = 1 and data equal to{'close_date': '0000-00-00', 'itemLink': 'https://example.com/opp/8f1efc97df214010b46631c74e6a8aa0/view?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1', 'organization': 'AGRICULTURE, DEPARTMENT OF', 'downloads': '', 'desc': 'Desc not found ', 'title': 'Potato Processing Floor Polishing'}
[1006/094709.813:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR [object Object]", source: https://example.com/token-assets/8e3b439bc40554e4bcb656864e9a1324/main.js (1)
[1006/094713.079:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR [object Object]", source: https://example.com/token-assets/8e3b439bc40554e4bcb656864e9a1324/main.js (1)
```

As you see before attempting to read some data from a div, it appears then I print my scraped data, when it goes for next divs, it again appears , I again get my second div content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \[object Object\] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean)

Comment: That's a JavaScript classic: if you just log an object it is shown in this less helpful form. Sometimes the console can "unfold" the object depending on how it was logged.  If not, you should use the browsers debugger, pretty format the JavaScript and put a breakpoint at the right line to get more information.