# output [object object] from array .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm having trouble mapping my gallery image urls into the src field. The output is [object object]. Any pointers on where im going on would be great!

code -

```
   <div className="image-grid">
                {data.home.galleryImage.map((url, index) => (
                      <div className="image-item" key={`${index}-cl`}>
                       <img src={url} alt={"no alt :("} />
                      </div>
                ))
                }
   </div>
```

graphql query -

```
export const query = graphql`
  query GetSingleHome($slug: String) {
    home: strapiHomes(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
    galleryImage {
      url
    }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `url` item is the iterable object, not the `url` itself. Change it to:

```
   <div className="image-grid">
                {data.home.galleryImage.map((image, index) => (
                      <div className="image-item" key={`${index}-cl`}>
                       <img src={image.url} alt={"no alt :("} />
                      </div>
                ))
                }
   </div>
```

Now your iterable object is `image` (what makes more sense), which contains an array of `galleryImage`, so to access the nested property you need to get `image.url`.

You can keep your previous approach using a destructing when declaring the iterable variable:

```
   <div className="image-grid">
                {data.home.galleryImage.map(({url}) => (
                      <div className="image-item" key={`${url}-cl`}>
                       <img src={url} alt={"no alt :("} />
                      </div>
                ))
                }
   </div>
```

For more information check the [`map` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map).