# Can’t querySelector from [object object] : VueJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to use google chart and i want to querySelector some element inside  and it return null

```
<template>
  <div class="pa-4">
    <GChart
      ref="gChart"
      :settings="{ packages: ['timeline'], state: timeRange }"
      type="Timeline"
      :data="chartData"
      :options="chartOptions"
      class="googleChart"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

In script:

```
  mounted() {
    this.nowLine()
  },
  methods: {
    nowLine() {
      const gchartQuery = document.querySelector('.googleChart')
      console.log(gchartQuery)
      console.log(this.$refs.gChart.$el)
    },
  },
```

and when console log it’s return

```
<div state="[object object]" class="googleChart">...</div>
```

and if i use this code:

```
const gchartQuery = document.querySelector('.googleChart rect')
console.log(gchartQuery)
```

it return null that i can’t query more element inside it.

Comment: How are you setting the `state` attribute of the DIV?

Comment: I didn't set it. It from component <GChart>

Comment: Something is trying to put an object in the attribute instead of a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean

Comment: Maybe you're calling a GChart function with the wrong type of argument.