# Console.log display object but save in localstorage is [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use function parseJwt to convert token, in console it display object, but when i save it in localstorage it display [object Object], and i cant use JSON.parse it in another component

[image: Console.log]
In localstorage
[image]

```
     localStorage.setItem('response', parseJwt(JSON.stringify(response.data.token)));
      console.log(parseJwt(JSON.stringify(response.data.token)));
```

Comment: Did you want to parse the token first, and then stringify it? `JSON.stringify(parseJwt(response.data.token))`?

Comment: in localStorage you can put in key or value just primitive type (number, bool, string) 
To store the object value you can use `JSON.stringify(yourObject)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local storage only supports storing `string`. So when you try storing an object like that, it won't work as expected. All you need to do, is stringify the object first:

```
localStorage.setItem('response', JSON.stringify(parseJwt(JSON.stringify(response.data.token))));
```

And the reason why you're seeing [object Object], is that [object Object] is the default string representation of a JavaScript Object. You can read more about here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean#:~:text=%5Bobject%20Object%5D%20is%20the%20default%20string%20representation%20of%20a%20JavaScript,alert(o)%3B%20%2F%2F%20foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean#:%7E:text=%5Bobject%20Object%5D%20is%20the%20default%20string%20representation%20of%20a%20JavaScript,alert(o)%3B%20%2F%2F%20foo)