# Response not expected after sending a post request using Content-Type "application/javascript" on fetch API is sent

Tags: javascript, json, request, fetch-api, content-type

When I send the following request from my Chrome devtools

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    title: 'foo',
    body: 'bar',
    userId: 1,
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/javascript',
  },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

This is the output I get:

> {id: 101}

Which is not what I expect, in fact I expect

> {title: 'foo', body: 'bar', userId: 1, id: 101}

that I get when I use Content-Type of 'aplication/json' like in the code below:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    title: 'foo',
    body: 'bar',
    userId: 1,
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you [follow the documentation for the service you are using](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/) and POST some JSON and say it is JSON then the server-side code processes it as you expect.

… but if you **disobey the documentation** and post an object which the browser converts to [the string `[object Object]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean) and (incorrectly) claim it is JavaScript then the server fails to process it.

This is normal behaviour and firmly in the "don't do that" category.

---

Aside: Allowing clients to post JavaScript programs which the server would (presumably) have to execute to do anything useful with would be extremely dangerous. This is a [whole category of security problems](https://www.checkpoint.com/cyber-hub/cyber-security/what-is-remote-code-execution-rce/) which developers try to *avoid*, not encourage.

[image: Doctor Doctor, it hurts when I do this! Don't do that.]