# When using screen.debug() on a React component that has an img element

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I am testing a React/Typescript component that has an image tag inside of it and wondering why, when running `screen.debug()`, the output shows the source being `src="[object Object]"`.

Here is the component I am testing:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { InfoType } from '../../constants'

type Props = {
    type: InfoType
}

const HelpWidget = ({ type }: Props) => {
    const [isHover, setHover] = useState<boolean>(false)

    return (
        <div className="help-widget">
            <img
                role="image"
                src={require('../../../public/images/info.svg')}
                onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
                onMouseOut={() => setHover(false)}
                onClick={() => setHover(!isHover)}
            />
            {isHover ? <div className="info">{type}</div> : <div role='hello'></div>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default HelpWidget
```

And here is the output I receive when running the test:

```
 <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="help-widget"
        >
          <img
            role="image"
            src="[object Object]"
          />
          <div
            role="hello"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

I am assuming that it may have to do with the fact that the source attribute is a JS expression within JSX but not entirely sure that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's JavaScript's default behavior when serializing an object. Here is a much better answer to how/why this happens https://stackoverflow.com/a/25419538/3088146

If this only happens in the context of react-testing-library it could be because of a build tool used to build the app that properly resolves it to the string but does not in react-testing-library