# How to use "object HTMLTableElement"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got a table on my site which I want to save in the session storage and replace it on button click (discard changes). Seems to work well to save it in session storage, but now I dont know how to make it usable for my HTML, that I can replace the current table with the table in my storage.

[Tried to convert it with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean) , but I only got this: [image]

I hoped that I can store it like this: [[image: table output2] and just set it later on.

This is my current code.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let table = document.querySelector('.overallTable');  
        sessionStorage.setItem('init', JSON.stringify(table));

        document.getElementById("dcChanges").addEventListener("click", function () {                                            
            if (sessionStorage.getItem('init') == sessionStorage.getItem('cache')) {console.log("equal")}
        });

        document.getElementById("saveInCache").addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.getElementsByClassName('overallTable');
            sessionStorage.setItem('cache', table);
            console.log(table);
            console.log("Output: Table: " + sessionStorage.getItem('cache'));
            console.log("Output: Converted: " + JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem('cache')));
        });
      });
```

I hoped I just could do something like this `document.getElementsByClassName("overallTable").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('cache');`

Comment: Don't recommend to store html element in localStorage. That being said you could use element.outerHTML to get the table as a string. I would say to store the data that makes up the table and rebuild the table after retrieving this said data

Comment: Keep in mind that the HTML is then really stored in the browsers of your visitors. If you change the website layout they will have the old HTML in their storage and it may break the layout if you are not careful in all new versions of the site. You should  rather store *data* that the element / your HTML table is made out of.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `html()` function of jQuery.

`$('.overallTable').html();`

Answer (score 1):

try `document.getElementsByClassName('overallTable')[0].innerHTML`