# "server: [object Object]" this is getting printed on the receivers screen

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

Building a chatApp using ws library.
**Server.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws'); // Import the 'ws' library

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('WebSocket server\n');
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

// Array to store connected clients
const clients = [];

wss.on('connection', ws => {
  console.log('Client connected');

  // Add client to the list
  clients.push(ws);

  ws.on('message', message => {
    console.log(`Received: ${message}`);

    // Broadcast message to all clients except the sender
    wss.clients.forEach(client => {
        if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          const dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ message, sender: 'server' });
          client.send(dataToSend);
        }
      });
  });

  ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
    removeClient(ws);
  });

  function removeClient(ws) {
    const index = clients.indexOf(ws);
    if (index !== -1) {
      clients.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});

const PORT = 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**client.js**

```
// client.js
let ws;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
  const chatWindow = document.getElementById('chat-window');

  // Event handler for incoming messages
  ws.onmessage = event => {
    const messageData = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log('Received message data:', messageData); // Debugging log
    const { message, sender } = messageData;

    if (sender !== 'self') {
      console.log('Appending message:', message); // Debugging log
      appendMessage(messageData); // No need to pass chatWindow here
    }
  };
});

// Function to send a message
function sendMessage() {
  const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
  const message = messageInput.value.trim();
  if (message !== '') {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ message }));
    messageInput.value = '';
  }
}

// Function to append a message to the chat window
function appendMessage(messageData) {
  const chatWindow = document.getElementById('chat-window'); // Access chatWindow directly
  const { message, sender } = messageData;

  console.log('Appending actual message:', message);
  const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
  messageElement.textContent = `${sender}: ${message}`; // Display sender's name with the message
  messageElement.classList.add('message-bubble');
  chatWindow.appendChild(messageElement);
  chatWindow.scrollTop = chatWindow.scrollHeight;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-btn');
  sendButton.addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
});
```

On sending message to other sockets it is printing `server: [object Object]` I am not able to get that also I logged the messages on the console [image]

So this is the screenshot of the console. Not able to get what might be the issue. Is it in type conversion or some other element is causing issue.
For more info below is the index.html code to give a better view
**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Real-Time Chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="./client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="chat-window" class="chat-box"></div>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text" id="message-input" placeholder="Type your message...">

      <button id="send-btn" onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \[object Object\] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean)

Comment: TLDR; the problem is in this line: `messageElement.textContent = \`${sender}: ${message}\`;`. `message` is an object and `[object Object]` is the default string representation. Either convert it to a string or overwrite the `toString` method.

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(message);` I console logged this value and it is logging `[object Object]`. @jabaa

Comment: Yes, that is the expected result. `[object Object]` is the default string representation. `{}.toString()` returns `[object Object]`. `\`${{}}\`` returns the same result: https://jsfiddle.net/ptn0cy31/ Either overwrite `toString` or create the string yourself.

Comment: `  const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(messageData.message.data);
    const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
    const stringValue = decoder.decode(uint8Array);
` I used this way to convert from Buffer to string value which I needed. Thanks for your help @jabaa

Comment: `messageElement.textContent = \`${sender}: ${message.data}\`` should also work